# Specialization of rational equivalence of zero cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f\colon \mathcal{X}\to B$ be a projective morphism of algebraic varieties. Let $X$ be the generic fiber of $f$. Let $Z_1,Z_2$ be effective zero-cycles on $X$, let $\overline{Z}_1,\overline{Z}_2$ be their closure in $\mathcal{X}$. Shrinking $B$, we may assume $\overline{Z}_i$ has relative dimension zero over $B$.

If $Z_1,Z_2$ are rationally equivalent, is it true that the fibers $(\overline{Z}_1)|_b,(\overline{Z}_2)|_b$ are rationally equivalent in $\mathcal{X}|_b$ for all $b\in B$?

(The rational equivalence is given by curves $C_j/k(B)$ mapping to $X$ and rational functions $f_j$ on $C_j$, so that $Z_1-Z_2=i_{j,*}\mathrm{div}(f_j)$. I think for all $b$ in a Zariski open subset $U\subset B$ where all $(C_j,f_j)$ can be exended, the classes $(\overline{Z}_1)|_b,(\overline{Z}_2)|_b$ are rationally equivalent, but am not sure about the $b\in B$ in general. Could $U$ be strictly proper?)

Comment: This is true (in a much more general context) at least if $B$ is smooth: see Fulton's *Intersection Theory*, §20.3.

Comment: @abx Just to make sure, in §20.3, it is mentioned that there is a specialization homomorphism from the open complement to the special fiber $A^i(X^\circ/S^\circ)\to A^i(\overline{X}/\overline{S})$. In our case , the $Z_1\sim Z_2$ holds over the generic point $\eta_{S^\circ}$, but not necessarily over $S^{\circ}$, the way to to fix this is we connect the special point and generic point by chain of DVRs, then reduce to the DVR case?

Comment: I don't think you need a chain, there is always a morphism from the spectrum of a DVR mapping the generic point to that of $B$, and the special point to any $b\in B$.

Comment: @abx I think we can blow up the closed point, and take the dvr, but the morphism on residue field would have a base change, I am not quite sure if the Chow group would be injective by purely transcendental base change..